# Pressing Escape or clicking outside the picker will close the Muix DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, typescript, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Following the example will close the DateTimePicker when clicking on the actions button; however, pressing Escape or clicking outside the picker will also close it. I need to close the DateTimePicker only when the user presses the action buttons.

I haven't come across any props to control this.

`<DesktopDatePicker closeOnSelect={false} slotProps={{ actionBar: { actions: ['cancel', 'accept'] } }} />`

Comment: is there any progress here? I want something similar. I want just don't update the date after clicking outside the calendar. I think this is firing ok when I click outside the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop called **'closeWidgets'** to use here.

Try doing it like this:

```
<DesktopDatePicker
  slotProps={{
    actionBar: {
      actions: ['cancel', 'accept'],
      onClose: (action) => closePickerOnAction(action) && closePicker(),
    },
  }}
  closeWidgets={false}
/>
```

Do let me know how it goes and works.

Comment: `closeWidgets={false}` is not a valid `prop`. Please refer to this api [datetimepicker api](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/)